# Android rawQuery in two condition

Tags: android, sqlite, count

I had problem about how to put `AND` condition in rawQuery . I want to `getCount WHERE SQLiteHelper.product_FId =listId AND SQLiteHelper.product_Status==1` ... Where should I add on another condition `WHERE SQLiteHelper.product_Status==1`  ?

```
public int getCountComplePro(String listId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] args = { listId };
        int x = 0;
        Cursor cur=database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "
                + SQLiteHelper.productTable + " WHERE "
                + SQLiteHelper.product_FId +"=?" ,args);

       x=cur.getCount();
```

}

```
        cur.close();
        return x;
```

Hope anyone can guide me in this problem ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] args = { listId };
Cursor cur=database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "
                + SQLiteHelper.productTable + " WHERE "
                + SQLiteHelper.product_FId +"=?"
                + "AND "+SQLiteHelper.product_Status+ "=1",args);
```

Shouldn't this do it?

Comment: ya , it is worked ...but it count all the product with product_Status=0

Comment: `String[] args = { listId, "1" };
Cursor cur=database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "
                + SQLiteHelper.productTable + " WHERE "
                + SQLiteHelper.product_FId +"=?"
                + "AND "+SQLiteHelper.product_Status+ "=?",args);`